# When "dfb_gfxcard_stretchblit" will go the software render flow at cobalt 19?

Tags: key, render, cobalt, directfb

1. My platform doesn't have gpu, so it uses directfb to draw UI and 
   handle event. It works fine at Cobalt 11.153049. But after I upgrade 
   it from cobalt 11 to cobalt19.lts.3, the directfb will go the software 
   render flow. The API  dfb_gfxcard_stretchblit of DFB1.5.3 will go the 
   software render flow.
2. When the issue happens, it can't show the UI correctly and can't 
   getEvent from dfb by the getEvent API. My starboard DirectFb code is 
   the same between Cobalt 11 and cobalt 19. So I am curious that why the 
   API will go the software render flow ?

Comment: Let me share my directfb flow at the starboard 
layer(window_internal.cc)
step 1: direct->GetDisplayLayer(direct , 0, &layer)
step 2: layer->CreateWindow(layer, &desc, &dfb_window)
step 3: dfb_window->CreateEventBuffer(...)
step 4: directfb->SetVideoMode(directfb, window_width, window_height, 
&kBPP). kBPP is 32.

Comment: Hello, you can check this link, I have shared the picture.  https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/131554396, when the NG happens, it will show green screen and goes software render. The Video can display normall, but the UI will show green screen at the top of the Video. If I remove the API call SetVideoMode, the green screen will disappear and show the normal UI, but the region not correctly. It still goes the DirectFB software render. Can you help check which element will affect the DirectFB that can lead it to go software render ?

Comment: Hello，I have also checked the directfb code, in fact, it will go the bellow flow at the line 2564.                                  https://github.com/deniskropp/DirectFB/blob/directfb-1.4/src/core/gfxcard.c#2564